# Problem with cv2.decomposeEssentialMat validation

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I have two calibrated cameras, I have their translation and rotation vector.
I tried to calculate the essential matrix from the parameters, and to reproduce the translation and rotation using `cv2.decomposeEssentialMat()` function, but the output translation and rotation is different from the translation and rotation I started with.
What I do wrong?

The initial translation and rotation:
`T=[-1.15051923, -0.16560349,  0.]`,
`R=`
`[[ 9.99840843e-01, -1.71024531e-02,  5.07888791e-03],`
`[ 1.71014523e-02,  9.99853731e-01,  2.40433213e-04],`
`[5.08225702e-03, -1.53538587e-04,  9.99987073e-01]]`

The function I use for essential calculation:

```py
    def get_essential(translation, rotation):
        tx = np.array([[0, -translation[2], translation[1]],
                       [translation[2], 0, -translation[0]],
                       [-translation[1], translation[0], 0]], dtype=np.float64)
        e = np.dot(rotation, tx)
        return e
```

and the output from `cv2.decomposeEssentialMat(e)` is:

```
R1 = array([[ 9.99840843e-01, -1.71024531e-02,  5.07888791e-03],
        [ 1.71014523e-02,  9.99853731e-01,  2.40433213e-04],
        [-5.08225702e-03, -1.53538587e-04,  9.99987073e-01]]),
R2 =  array([[ 9.54428587e-01,  2.98396176e-01, -5.07888791e-03],
        [ 2.98398850e-01, -9.54441234e-01, -2.40433213e-04],
        [-4.91924439e-03, -1.28605798e-03, -9.99987073e-01]]),
T =  array([[ 0.98720504],
        [ 0.15937592],
        [-0.00505229]])
```

Comment: R1 seems to be right. Could you try `cv2.decomposeEssentialMat(-e)`?

Answer (score 0):

Vector T can't be found entirely so that by default opencv cv2 return a normalized vector.
If you normalize your input vector you have the correct result!